# Почему не разворачивается спрайт в pygame?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame, спрайт

Почему не разворачивается спрайт в pygame?

```
import random
import os
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 300
FPS = 70
UP = 0
DOWN = 180
RIGHT = -90
LEFT = 90
# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
turn=0
# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "img")
go = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, "car.png")).convert()
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = go
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        self.rot = 0
    def update(self, turn):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        

        print(turn)  
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8        
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, turn)
        self.rect = image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        screen.blit(image, self.rect)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

# Цикл игры
running = True
turn=0
while running:
    # Держим цикл на правильной скорости
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Ввод процесса (события)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверка для закрытия окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                turn=90
          
    all_sprites.update(turn)
    # Рендеринг
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # После отрисовки всего, переворачиваем экран
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

когда нажимаешь на левую стрелку машинка должна развернуться на 90 градусов, но этого не происходит. Почему?

Comment: Что выводит `print(turn)`?

Comment: я уже решил - просто убрал отрисовку "all_sprites.draw(screen)"

Comment: @АндрейТаков  на stackoverflow не принято "отмечать" вопросы как решенные. Нужно или добавить ответ, или удалить вопрос, если он не актуален.